# How to know if I have the correct access rights to my Github Repo?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

Guys I am having an absolute nightmare...

I have two git accounts that I am constantly switching between and I usually use HTTPs over SSH. 
However I now need to use SSH as one of the files I want to push is a mp4 file and is quite large (push didn't seem to be working over HTTPs).

I've followed a few online suggestions on how to set up my github account to use SSH but I still get this same error...

*ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

I have generated a SSH key and added it to my github account as shown on this page...
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Please help me get to the bottom of this, I am working on a site for a friend and I really need to start pushing code up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The default key `id_rsa` is used by default for all accounts. The easiest way to get this to work is to ensure that that's the name of the key you generated. If you provide your own name, you'll have to specify it using ssh config.

One simple way to test is using `ssh -T` or even `ssh -vT`

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi <user>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! 

When I do that I get this output...


Hi bmcgowan94! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.